# SWT Scale with dual thumbs

Tags: eclipse, swt

SWT's **Scale** component supports only a single thumb, and I have the need for two, in order to show a value range (ie. one thumb is the lower limit, the other the upper limit).

Can anybody **a)** point me in the direction of one (commercial or free, Google's been no help), or **b)** suggest the best way to go about implementing one from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, in case it benefits others in a similar situation: the [Opal](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/) project's [RangeSlider](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/RangeSlider) appears to provide the functionality I'm after.